# Android Studio - Problema con conexión a SQL Server

Tags: android, sql, sql-server

En mi proyecto de Android Studio estoy tratando de llenar un Recycler View con información de una Base de datos de SQL Server.

Vale aclarar que ya tengo una Base de datos creada en SQLServer con algunos registros, para hacer esta prueba. Lo único que necesito hacer es consultar la información para llenar mi Recycler.

El problema es que no puedo realizar la conexión, ya que no sé cual es el usuario y la contraseña que tengo que colocar de SQL Server, porque me conecto como "Windows Authentication" el cual no pide ni user ni pass.

Así realizo mi conexión:

```
    public Connection conexionBD(){
    Connection conexion=null;
    try{
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conexion= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.157;databaseName=Myapp;user=?;password=?;");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return conexion;
}
```

Tampoco estoy seguro si el IP que debo ingresar es el IPv4 o el "Puerta de enlace predeterminada".

Comment: Como sugerencia, no uses JTDS, que es un driver viejo, sin soporte, que no soporta JDBC4.0 completo. Usa [el que provee MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). La IP debe ser la IP del servidor.

Comment: pues la duda aqui deberia ser como crear un usuario en SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Para autenticarse a una BD Sql Server, es necesario usar la opción `intergatedSecurity` de acuerdo a [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

```
jdbc:sqlserver://;servername=server_name;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=<authSchema>
```

Faltaría revisar cómo garantizar que la autenticación sea exitosa. Y no uses jTds, que es un proyecto abandonado. Habría que comenzar por:

- añadir en las propiedades de conexión `authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated`
- Incluir en el proyecto las librerías que indican para poderse autenticar con WindowsAuthentication:

> Important: If authentication is set to ActiveDirectoryIntegrated, the
>   following two libraries need to be installed: SQLJDBC_AUTH.DLL
>   (available in the JDBC driver package) and Azure Active Directory
>   Authentication Library for SQL Server (ADALSQL.DLL) It's available in
>   different languages (for both x86 and amd64) from the download center
>   at Microsoft Active Directory Authentication Library for Microsoft SQL
>   Server. The JDBC driver only supports version 1.0.2028.318 and higher
>   for the ADALSQL.DLL.

- Si se usa JavaKerberos o NLTM para conectarse al servidor donde está la BD. Esto con la propiedad `authenticationScheme`. JavaKerberos tiene todo un proceso; NLTM requiere que especifiques **el dominio, el usuario y la contraseña en el OS donde está la BD.**

> When using authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos, you must specify the
>   fully qualified domain name (FQDN) in the serverName or serverSpn
>   property. Otherwise, an error occurs (Server not found in Kerberos
>   database).
>
> For more information on using authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos, see
>   Using Kerberos integrated authentication to connect to SQL Server.
>
> When using authenticationScheme=NTLM, you must specify the Windows
>   domain to authenticate in using NTLM in domain or domainName property,
>   as well as the Windows credentials in user or userName and password
>   properties. Otherwise, an error occurs (connection properties must be
>   specified).

Más info sobre cómo fijar las propiedades de conexión aquí: [Documentación MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: pero no responde a mi pregunta, no se que poner en user y pass si yo no uso ninguno para acceder a mi base de datos

Comment: @RodrigoPaz Ya edité la respuesta. No se pone ningún usuario y contraseña de la BD...

Comment: eso esta resuelto, el problema es que en el Connection conexionDB() el return me toma el valor null; definido al principio y no lo que está adentro del try catch. Estuve intentado pero no logré hacerlo funcionar